# Upload file with React

Tags: reactjs, forms, upload

I want to make a simple file upload form on the front end. Then, on the backend, I would pass the information about that file to an API.

Here is my front-end code where I call a specific function on the back end and pass the data:

```
import React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

const Upload = () => {
  // a local state to store the currently selected file.
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = React.useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {

    event.preventDefault()
    
    //Got all the Infos about my file
    console.log(selectedFile)
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("selectedFile", selectedFile);

     //Empty result
    console.log(formData)

    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/upload", {
      //I will pass the data to a function in the backend
      params: {
        data: formData,
      },
      
    })
      .then((Response) => {
        console.log(Response)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  const handleFileSelect = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0])
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileSelect}/>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
  )
};

export default Test
```

On the back-end side, a route call the method

`router.get('/upload?', Upload);`

Then finally the function in the backend to process

```
const ApiProcess = (req, res) => {
  var axios = require('axios');
  var data = req.query

  console.log(req.query)
 
//All the API Stuff
  
}
```

But the problem is that I receive empty data in the Backend. What's wrong with my code?

Thanks

EDIT

On backend side I use multer and add 'app.use(multer().any())' on top of index file. That help cause now I cant access in backend to a simple formData. Now my function that receive the data log this '[Object: null prototype] {}'

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution. I missed a piece of middleware to process Multipart/formdata on Express Side :

```
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
//Set the destination folder and Naming of the file that is upload
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
  })
  
  const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

Then I process the formData with the files
router.post('/upload', upload.array("file"),Upload);
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is because your file is not getting forwarded from frontend
use `FileReader` instead

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" onChange={(e) => 
setFile(e.target.files)} />

const data = new FormData();

data.append(file[0])
```

and then you can access the file data on `file[0]` index and after storing the data you can forward it to the backend

Comment: Thx for your answer. But it's more or less what I'm doing no? First when input file change I set the State with `event.target.files[0]` and then when form is submit I create `const data` and append the state inside. It's the same approach no ?

Answer (score 0):

there are some problems in your code.

first of all an upload request usually is a `post` type. and also you should send `Content-Type` header with your request. so:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/upload", formData {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'Multipart/formData',
  },
})
```

when you log `formData` it's always empty. you can use some methods like `formData.keys()` or `formData.values()` to see inside it.

Comment: Thank you @pedram . When I console.log `formData.keys()` or `formData.values()` it returns the same thing : `Iterator{}`. And when I use post, should I change the route on backend side (I'm using express-router) ? `router.post('/upload?', Upload)` instead of router.get('/upload?', Upload) ?

Comment: @ArthurFortin yes change it to `post`

Comment: thanks. The problem now is that the function at backend doesn't get the formData, even if I use a string for test. It's an empty body.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is not a problem with the router that set between my front script and my backend script that process API calls. So I send formData with Axios POST to express router that handle this way `router.post('/upload', Upload)` and then the function `const Upload = (req, res) => { console.log(req)}`. Am I missing something @pedram ?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with `nodejs` concepts, but I think your code is correct